Iam unable to explode the model floor wise in autodesk forge viewer
Iam using autodesk forge viewer.Iam unable to explode the model by floor wise instead it is exploding every element in the model which makes my viewer clumsy so please help me to get ouyt of this problem
this is how it is coming
but i want the model to explode like thissee how clear it is 

The function that you are using is not really made for buildings and makes more sense for small products or mechanical components.
To create a vertical explode of each level, you can refer to this article: View each floor using vertical explode.
It's a little outdated now, but some parts of the logic can be reused for your purpose. You can use the AEC metadata for example to get the bounding box of each level.

But in this documentation
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/view-each-floor-using-vertical-explode
they are passing some fragids statically  from not exploding.This is not the correct case i think.
suppose if i have n number of models and i want to load and explode them then it is difficult to do the floor wise explosion according to the above document.

The only static info in the sample are the viewer states. Everything else is dynamic. Currently it just looks at the bottom of every object to set their new position, so every object whose bottom aligns (walls, floors, etc) will move together, but anything above that (maybe a vase on the table?) will move separate. As Alex said the sample could be improved if things were based on the AEC metadata.

I updated the sample using AEC Model Data: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/explode-along-levels
